Geometric way to obtain region in plane closest to given edge of a polygon
I have a polygon in the plane. One edge E is selected. Is there a simple way to visualize the region in the plane containing all the points for which the edge E is the closest (smallest perpendicular distance) among all edges of the polygon?
I was trying to think along the lines of angle bisectors of normals of edges and next edges, but can't pin down the formula or algorithm for the exact region. In other words, this would partition the plane into points closest to the edges. I also looked up Voronoi diagrams, and this sounds similar, but curious to know if there's a simpler way for polygons or even convex polygons.

The boundary of such a region looks like a combination of straight lines and parabolas but I don't think it's particularly nice.

@Pranay I don’t think we’d get parabolas, as we are comparing distances from 2 lines, not a line and a point.

@SohamSaha But an edge isn’t a line, it’s a line segment with end points. So you end up with line segments and parabolic segments.

@Pranay Ah, so you’re thinking in that way. I think the OP should clarify, whether distances are measured from the edge segments or from the perpendiculars dropped on to the infinitely extended edges

No assumption of convexity for your polygon ?
